# Finding the general solution to the inhomogenous system y' = Ay +f where...

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know how to find the eigenvalues and associated vectors, but I don't know how to finish off the problem when it involves complex values.

The eigenvalues are $\lambda = 2+i, 2-i$

Would someone kindly guide me through what to do next? I have been searching high and low online and offline to no avail.

So, the problem is as the title says, "Find the general solution to the inhomogenous system $y' = Ay + f$

where

A = $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $f= \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ e^{2t} \end{pmatrix}$

The answer is $y(t) = C_1e^{2t}\begin{pmatrix} sin (t) - cos (t) \\ cos (t) \end{pmatrix} + C_2e^{2t}\begin{pmatrix}-cos (t) - sin (t) \\ sin (t) \end{pmatrix}+e^{2t}\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next step is to find the eigenvectors.  In fact, all you need is an eigenvector for one of the eigenvalues.  If, say, $u = \pmatrix{a + b i\cr c + d i\cr}$ (with $a,b,c,d$ real) is an eigenvector for $\lambda = 2 + i$, then its complex conjugate
$\overline{u} = \pmatrix{a - b i\cr c - d i\cr}$ is an eigenvector for $\overline{\lambda} = 2 - i$.
And the real and imaginary parts of $u e^{\lambda t}$ are a fundamental set of (real) solutions of the homogeneous system.   Notice that $$(a + b i)e^{(2 + i)t} = (a + b i) e^{2t} (\cos(t) + i \sin(t)) = ((a \cos(t) - b \sin(t)) + i (a \sin(t) + b \cos(t)))e^{2t}$$
so its real part is $(a \cos(t) - b \sin(t)) e^{2t}$ and its imaginary
part is $(a \sin(t) + b \cos(t)) e^{2t}$.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I've gotten that far using the Eigen value $\lambda = 2 + i$ and I've found that the associated eigenvector is \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1-i \end{pmatrix} but even at this point I don't understand how the book arrived at its answer... Did it chose a different eigenvalue/vector?

Comment: It chose a different eigenvector: $\pmatrix{-1-i\cr 1\cr}$, which is $(1+i)/2$ times yours, so it gets a different but equivalent answer.

Comment: After that, you want to find a particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation.  Since $2$ is not an eigenvalue, there will be a solution of the form $e^{2t} v$ where $v$ is a constant vector.